# How can I change redirect_uri for external authentication when behind a reverse proxy?

Tags: c#, asp.net, openid-connect

Everything works fine with kestrel only but when I'm behind a reverse proxy (I'm using nginx), the redirect_uri produced by the external middleware does not have the correct scheme (http instead of https).
Kestrel (or the middleware [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount/8.0.0-preview.6.23329.11)) seems to ignore `X-Forwarded-Proto` header.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(o =>
    {
        o.DefaultScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
        o.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
    })
    .AddMicrosoftAccount(microsoftOptions =>
    {
        microsoftOptions.ClientId = "xxxx";
        microsoftOptions.ClientSecret = "xxxx";
        // May be more settings here
    });
....

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseForwardedHeaders();
```